# How can I create a Lifetime subscription with Woocommerce Subscriptions Plugin?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

How can I create a Variable Subscription product with a variation with lifetime validity and no payment for every year yet I need a Signup fee

Thanks for your time fellows.

Answer (score 1):

I can see how you'd think this would a subscription, but since the user won't be making further payments, maybe it's easier to sell as a simple product?

Like back in the old days when they used to sell the unlimited travel tickets.

Not really a subscription per say, as user pays a lot up front and get's to keep it for life.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jack.
I have added them as variations for a product that is why I can't use it differently.